# jQuery animate: Bounce from right to left in smooth steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to bounce an element and move it from right to left in smooth steps.

Below is what I've tried but I couldn't get a nice smooth effect. If I remove `right: '+=5px'` from jQuery, it animates more smoothly but still not exactly what I am looking for.

I also want to display div with text once the ball stops animating. I couldn't figure that out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ball-wrapper").queue(function() {

    $(this).animate({top: '+=150px'}, {duration: 500, queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '0px', right: '+=5px'}, {duration: 500, queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '+=120px'}, {duration: 500, queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '0px', right: '+=5px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '+=100px'}, {duration: 500,queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '0px', right: '+=5px'}, {duration: 500,queue: true});
    $(this).animate({top: '+=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: true});
    $(this).animate({right: '+=600px'}, {duration: 3500, queue: false});

    $.dequeue(this);
  });
  
  $(".ball-wrapper .text").css('display','block');
});
```

```css
.ball-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:right;
  border-radius:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.ball-wrapper .text {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bouncing-wrapper">
  <div class="ball-wrapper">
    <span class="ball"></span>
    <span class="text">Text text...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this article: http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/tutorial-simple-jquery-bouncing-ball/

in http://jsfiddle.net/c23sye45/1/ I added new code:

```
$('#ball').animate({
        left: '100px'
    },
    {        
        duration: 3500, 
        queue: false,
        easing:'linear',
        complete:function(){
          $('#ball').stop(true);
            $('#text').show();
        }
  });
```

Maybe this will help